# Weird case of AccessViolation while using overlapped IO in Windows

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I've been experimenting with Overlapped IO feature of Win32 API, namely `ReadFileEx` and `WriteFileEx` functions.

Here is a simplest example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

const DWORD blockSize = 512;
char buffer[blockSize];

bool done = false;

OVERLAPPED overlapped;

void Completion(DWORD error, DWORD read, LPOVERLAPPED overlapped) {

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring fileName;
    std::wcout << "Enter file name: ";
    std::getline(std::wcin, fileName);

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(
        fileName.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL
    );
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::wcout << "Error while opening file: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    overlapped.Offset = overlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;
    ReadFileEx(file, buffer, blockSize, &overlapped, (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE) &Completion);

    while (!done)
        SleepEx(1000, TRUE);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm starting overlapped reading with `ReadFileEx` and waiting for it to finish using `SleepEx`. Although `Completion` has empty body and the program should hang forever after reading first block, it does something completely different. In fact, it raises AccessViolation with code `0xC0000005` on the first call to `SleepEx`. This happens on Windows machines with Win 7 and Win Vista I've tried, including fresh 64 bit virtual machine with Windows 7. But, curiously, it does not fail on one Windows 8.1 machine and runs just as expected. This was compiled with Visual Studio 2010, but I don't think it matters.

I can not understand what have I done wrong, so if anyone knows the answer, please help me.

Comment: Never, *never*, cast a function pointer to stop the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Casting the function doesn't change what it is. It isn't the right type. Period. You lied to the compiler and reaped the inevitable consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback must be of the following form, as stated clearly in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364052(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
  _In_    DWORD        dwErrorCode,
  _In_    DWORD        dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
  _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

Your function has the wrong calling convention. Your cast does not change that. It is simply a way for you to stop the compiler rejecting your ill-formed program. Don't lie to the compiler. Correct the function declaration by adding the `CALLBACK` calling convention.